# Windows-1256 problem on localhost apache server

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have to modify some php web pages. Web pages have Charest windows-1256 in meta tags working well on server but in my local host it shows me some strange characters. Some pages have static contents and some are database driven but output is same.
How can I make my local server to support windows-1256?
I installed appserv, Php version is 5.3, database is same as it is on server.[image: sample image][image: Another sample image]

Comment: PHP5.3 ?? Really!! That has not been supported since Aug 2014?

Comment: Check what `default_charset` is set to. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right but is an old server so I kept same on localhost like web server. But don’t know how to make it able to support windows-1256

Comment: I sorted static contents by adding window-1256 in php.ini as default charset but still database contents are not correct. In mysql tables are in Latin_swedish_ci and database collation is utf8-general-ci. Please help what should I do?